# Convert projects to .Net 4.5 ( that uses TPL)

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, base-class-library

Currently own a few projects with .net 3.5 and .net 4.0.
It was decided to migrate all to .NET 4.5.

All projects are already in VS2012 (C# 5.0) and all projects using async-await keywords

On .net 4.0 projects is being used Microsoft.Bcl.Async 
On .net 3.5 projects is being used AsyncBridge.Net35 and TaskParallelLibrary

The problem is:
- There is no TaskEx class and other extension methods in .net 4.5 or I do not know the existence of these

How can I make this change, without major changes in the code?

Comment: Wasn't `TaskEx` just something they used in the async preview? I think that in .NET 4.5 this is simply called `Task`, and the methods should be included in the standard libraries. Or what other extension methods in particular are you missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .NET 4.5, the `TaskEx` methods have been moved into the `Task` class. For example, instead of `await TaskEx.Run(...);`, you use `await Task.Run(...);`. You should, assuming your naming scheme of your own classes is sane, be able to do a global search-and-replace.

Answer (score 1):

As part of your migration, you should change your `TaskEx` calls to `Task` calls.

Comment: I'll have to change the TaskEx.Run to Task.Factory.Start? (I don't want to do this)

Comment: @J.Lennon Nope, just `Task.Run`.

Comment: Also, `TaskEx.RunEx` becomes just `Task.Run`.